# «Камень преткновения» — это помеха или препятствие?

Tags: грамотная-речь, этимология, значение-слов

Меня интересует, как правильно понимать и использовать в речи метафору «камень преткновения».

Происхождение метафоры связывают с Библией:

> Ибо так говорил мне Господь, держа на мне крепкую руку и внушая мне не
> ходить путём сего народа, и сказал: «Не называйте заговором всего
> того, что народ сей называет заговором; и не бойтесь того, чего он
> боится, и не страшитесь. Господа Саваофа — Его чтите свято, и Он —
> страх ваш, и Он — трепет ваш! И будет Он освящением и **камнем
> преткновения**, и скалою соблазна для обоих домов Израиля, петлею и
> сетью для жителей Иерусалима. И многие из них преткнутся и упадут, и
> разобьются, и запутаются в сети, и будут уловлены». *(Книга пророка Исаии. Глава 8)*

Но, честно сказать, когда читаешь этот отрывок:

- во-первых, не наступает понимание, что же такое камень преткновения;
- во-вторых, складывается впечатление, что эта метафора на момент написания текста уже существовала, и автор просто её использовал.

Согласно словарю Ушакова:

> преткну́ться, ну́сь, нёшься, сов. (к претыкаться) (книжн. ритор.).
> **Споткнуться**. *Тебя подхватим, чтобы пятою о камень не преткнулся ты.*
> Блок.

Таким образом, преткнуться — это споткнуться.

Получается, что камень преткновения — это камень спотыкания, или тот камень, о который спотыкаются.

Если порассуждать: то, обо что мы спотыкаемся физически, нам мешает идти, но нас не останавливает. Если дорога будет вся в камнях, и мы будем о них спотыкаться, то мы будем двигаться, но с помехами. Камни на дороге — это не стена на дороге.

Поэтому переносное значение камней, о которые мы спотыкаемся на пути, может быть — помехи, но не препятствия.

Рассмотрим такие цитаты:

> «Женщины — это главный камень преткновения в деятельности человека».
> Толстой Л. Н., Анна Каренина, 1877

В данном случае использование, вроде, правильное как помехи. Т. е. человек живёт, осуществляет деятельность, но у него есть помехи — любовные страсти, которые его отвлекают, например, от достижения поставленных целей.

> И искусство имеет свой предел. Есть камень преткновения, который
> решительно не берет ни смычок, ни кисть, ни резец. Герцен, Концы и
> начала.

Тут «камень преткновения» рассматривается, как препятствие, которое нельзя преодолеть.

Так всё-таки, как правильно понимать и употреблять «камень преткновения», как помеху или как препятствие? И почему?

Если метафора происходит не из Библии, то какова её истинная этимология?